# Change Ubuntu 18.04 Plymouth Color

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04

Have recently moved to Ubuntu 18.04 and have setup using an ecnrypted LVM but for the life of me am unable to update the purple background color in the plymouth configs located at

```
/usr/share/plymouth/themes/
```

So many articles have different ways (*default.grub* or *ubuntu-logo.script*) in different places but so far none of these are working.

Does anyone know how to update the plymouth background color in 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

In terminal:

1. cd /usr/share/plymouth/themes
2. Sudo gedit default.grub
3. Change the following X's with your preferred RGB color:

   if background_color X,X,X,X;

For example, 0,0,0 is black:

```
if background_color 0,0,0;
```

4. Save and exit gedit.
5. Sudo update-grub
6. **Optional**: Check using grub-emu:

a)sudo apt install grub-emu

b)sudo grub-emu

*To exit grub-emu, just exit the running terminal.

Now you have a new background color:)

---

Bonus - change other colors:

At step 3., add the following without the '#' part:

```
set menu_color_highlight=white/light-gray # Highlighted text will be white with a 
light-gray background.
set menu_color_normal=white/black # Normal text will be white with a black background.
set color_normal=white/black # Text that can't be chosen will be white on black.
```

These are the colors you can choose, according to Ubuntu's website: [Color Variety](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays#GRUB_2_Colors)

> black
>
> blue
>
> brown
>
> cyan
>
> dark-gray
>
> green
>
> light-cyan
>
> light-blue
>
> light-green
>
> light-gray
>
> light-magenta
>
> light-red
>
> magenta
>
> red
>
> white
>
> yellow